# How to make my hillshade bright as given in the link?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I am trying to make a hillshade of a terrain. The issue I am facing is that the model looks dull as like the default models available in blender. I am attaching the screenshot of my workspace and nodes.

**My model**
[image]

**Node**

[image]

The output I am trying to achieve is as below https://somethingaboutmaps.com/Shaded-Relief-in-Blender
[image]

The tutorial which I followed is https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/2017/11/16/creating-shaded-relief-in-blender/

[image]

Comment: I don't get why you ask a question and also provide a link to a tutorial which explains with many details how to do it? What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: Have you seen the sun/light part?

Comment: I added sun but less effect

Comment: The node indicated in your question seems ok. Can you upload your file (with the texture included/packed)?

Comment: Here's a hint... to have shadows you need light... the intensity and placement of the light will determine the brightness of the scene and the angle for the shadows. The color of the environment (the world) will determine how dark or bright the shadows will be.

Comment: Unplug that brightness contrast node from the volume. it makes no sense. Same thing  with the alpha to color mix node that connects to nothing...

Comment: I uploaded the blend file. Please suggest any methods

Comment: The image texture was not packed in your file. But all is fine in your settings. The main thing is to change the point light by a sunlight (with strength of 1) and orientate it as you want. You can also add an environment texture.

Comment: .. and be aware that the color of your _world_ is contributing ambient light, filling unlit areas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is matter of lights in your settings as also said susu in the comments.

Just an example from your file (but with another texture because you did not pack your texture in the file).

[image]

Only things changed are the lights.

I've changed the point light by a sun light and gave it an orientation and a strength of one (= one solar unit, our sun).

[image]

And added an environment texture (you can take hdri textures from Blender's install directory, in the data part):

[image]

From that, up to you changing color, texture, light intensity, etc.

Comment: you don't really need an HDR for this, a simple dark gray color for the world would do. The darker the world, the more contrast you'll get in the shadows.

Comment: @susu, this was just to provide some options to Gokul. But feel free to elaborate around this (or other) answering yourself (the more advices provided the more this is contributing to the site).